# IKEv2 connection from OSX to Windows RRAS disconnects after eight minutes

Tags: vpn, mac-osx, ikev2

Using Windows as a VPN client everything works perfectly fine.
When I establish a connection using the integrated IKEv2 client on my Mac (OS X 10.11.6), I get disconnected after eight minutes. Until then it works perfectly as well.

Log on the Mac says: `Failed to generate IKE SA crypto values`

Event log on the server says `The reason for disconnecting was administrative settings or explicit request` (it says the same when I disconnect manually)

I assume there is a mismatch in encryption methods/ciphers between OSX and Windows Server 2012 R2 RRAS during the rekeying process but I can't find a way to modify those settings on the client.

Unfortunately L2TP is not a viable option. Alternatives like OpenVPN that require a 3rd party client aren't either.

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks in advance :-)

Kind regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcard certificate was the problem. Everything turned out fine as soon as I switched to an appropriate SAN certificate. I made sure that the common name is also listed as a subject alternative name.